# Pasting Excel range into Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to paste an array of cells range into a document.

I tried different codes and watched tutorials.

This code seems to do everything except paste to the email.
If I manually paste the last cell range that was copied it seems to copy the range as it should.

```
Sub RangeToOutlook_Multi()

    'Declare Outlook Variables
    Dim oLookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oLookItm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oLookIns As Outlook.Inspector
    
    'Declare Word Variables
    Dim oWrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oWrdRng As Word.Range
    
    'Delcare Excel Variables
    Dim RngArray As Variant
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Get the Active instance of Outlook if there is one
    Set oLookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    'If Outlook isn't open then create a new instance of Outlook
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        'Clear Error
        Err.Clear
        'Create a new instance of Outlook
        Set oLookApp = New Outlook.Application
    End If
        
    'Create a new email
    Set oLookItm = oLookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    'Create an array to hold ranges
    RngArray = Array(Sheet6.Range("A101:E112"), Sheet6.Range("G101:K111"))

    With oLookItm
        'Define some basic info of our email
        .To = "xyz@abc.com"
        .CC = "xyz@abc.com"
        .Subject = "Here are all of my Ranges"
        .Body = "Here are all the Ranges from my worksheet."

        'Display the email
        .Display
        
        'Get the Active Inspector
        Set oLookIns = .GetInspector
        
        'Get the document within the inspector
        Set oWrdDoc = oLookIns.WordEditor
        
      For Each Item In RngArray
            Item.Copy
            
            'Define the range, insert a blank line, collapse the selection.
            Set oWrdRng = oWrdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
            oWrdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                
            'Add a new paragragp and then a break
            Set oWrdRng = oWdEditor.Paragraphs.Add
            oWrdRng.InsertBreak
                        
            'Paste the object.
            oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out that `On Error Resume Next` and report back on the line that throws an error and the error message.

Comment: Add `On Error GoTo 0` After the `End If` and then check where are you getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

In the code the `oWrdRng`  object is overwritten in the loop:

```
 For Each Item In RngArray
        
            Item.Copy
            
            'Define the range, insert a blank line, collapse the selection.
            Set oWrdRng = oWrdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
                oWrdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                
            'Add a new paragragp and then a break
            Set oWrdRng = oWdEditor.Paragraphs.Add
            oWrdRng.InsertBreak
                        
            'Paste the object.
            oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
        
     Next
```

The [Document.Paragraphs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.paragraphs) property returns a `Paragraphs` collection that represents all the paragraphs in the specified document. So, it seems you need to change the code in the following way:

```
 For Each Item In RngArray
        
            Item.Copy
            
            'Define the range, insert a blank line, collapse the selection.
            Set oWrdRng = oWrdDoc.Content
            oWrdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                
            'Add a new paragragp and then a break
            Set oWrdRng = oWrdDoc.Paragraphs.Add
            oWrdRng.InsertBreak
                        
            'Paste the object.
            oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
        
     Next
```

Finally, I'd recommend debugging the code first if something is not working as it should, so you could refer to the specific line of code if something fails unexpectedly.

Comment: Thank you, i tried this but nothing changed, same problem. but i comented out the `on error resume next` and after that i got an Error from this line of code `Set oWrdDoc = oLookIns.WordEditor` Error message: Runtime error '287': Application-defined or object-defined error